# IntelliJ template function to convert variable name to constant variable name (uppercase with underscore)

Tags: templates, intellij-idea

I'd like to convert a member variable / field name like "fooBar" into FOO_BAR within a custom setter generator template similar to what refactor --> Introduce Constant does. Is there an function available to do this? I looked at the IntelliJ StringUtils class but could not find a method that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer hidden in an IntelliJ issue

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152774

```
$NameUtil.capitalizeAndUnderscore($field.name)
```